# Foreign key in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys

i have 3 tables products ,categories an pro_cat.
pro_cat has 2 foreign keys pro_id references to products->id and cat_id references to categories->id .
i want when i add new product to the products table to add the id of the product and the id of category in pro_cats table.
so i can retrieve it later ... how can i do it ?
my insert query to products 
[image: 1]

```
$query="INSERT INTO products (name,description,price
```

Comment: Your query is very incomplete - can you share the rest of it?

Comment: If your table products doesn't have the category ID as I imagine, then you just have to do two inserts. Insert into products then insert into pro_cat. The only way around that would be to create a trigger on the products table that somehow retrieves the category from somewhere else and inserts it into the pro_cat table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate table '`pro_cat`' in this purpose. Instead, you should create an extra column something like '`product_id`' to the '`categories`' table.

Each time your store an entity to '`products`' table, you should have an unique '`id`' of this row. So, in '`categories`' table this '`id`' must be stored in '`product_id`' column. For example:

```
Products
id   name       description
1    product1   Product1 description
2    product2   Product2 description

Categories
id   name                product_id
1    product1_category   1
2    product2_category   2
```